# Install/Upgrade bash using Spack under macOS Catalina

Tags: bash, macos

I'm using macOS `Catalina` and Spack `0.16.2-3063`.

I'm trying to install a new `bash` version and make it the default one for my user.

> I was trying to do the same with `Nix`, but I couldn't advance any further, so I'm trying Spack instead.

So I'm following [this guide](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/workflows.html#using-spack-to-replace-homebrew-conda), and lucky enough their example is with `bash`. Resuming, I did run these commands:

```bsh
$ spack env create default
$ spack add bash
$ nano ~/.spack/var/spack/environments/default/spack.yaml
# ...and add/change concretization: together
$ spack concretize
$ spack install
```

My `~/.spack/var/spack/environments/default/spack.yaml` file at this point looks like:

```yaml
spack:
  concretization: together
  specs:
    - bash
  view: true
```

Then I change the default shell to the newer Bash version:

```bsh
$ sudo nano /etc/shells
# ...add /Users/x80486/.spack/var/spack/environments/default/.spack-env/view/bin/bash
$ chsh -s /Users/x80486/.spack/var/spack/environments/default/.spack-env/view/bin/bash
```

At this point I even restarted the system, but somehow something is not working.

```bsh
$ echo $SHELL
/Users/x80486/.spack/var/spack/environments/default/.spack-env/view/bin/bash

$ echo $BASH_VERSION
5.1.8(1)-release

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release
...
```

I would expect that `bash --version` would return the one that I previously changed. Moreover, `which -a bash` does not list `/Users/x80486/.spack/var/spack/environments/default/.spack-env/view/bin/bash` either.

So what am I missing in this setup? It looks to work fine except for that "final touch".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this works as it stands. I was missing activating/loading the `default` environment (by default) every time a new shell is started.

So just by adding this line: `spack env activate default` to any of the dotfiles that are sourced initially will do it — in my case I put it after I source the Spack's `setup-env.sh` file.